# How to access a custom control dependency propery from its viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, custom-controls

I'm working on a multiple document viewer (a simple window with a custom control, each with a separate viewmodel). When clicking on a filename, a new instance of the user control is added to the main window. The user control has a dependency property which holds the path to the filename, defined in it's code-behind. Now i'm struck on how to get the value of this property from the user control to the viewmodel, so it can show the actual document. Any Hints?

```
    <ctrl:DocViewerControl x:Key="docviewer" DocumentSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Path, ElementName=docList}"/>
```

I use this code in main window to make new instances of my user control where DocumentSource is the dependency property i need access to, as stated above.

**Edit:**

Following is the (relevant) code for the view and the viewmodel of my control, specific to the dependancy property value capture problem i have.

UserControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ToolboxControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DocumentSource",
        typeof(string), typeof(ToolboxControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDocumentSourceChanged)));

    public ToolboxControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string DocumentSource
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DocumentSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DocumentSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    private static void OnDocumentSourceChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

PV_ViewModel.cs

```
public class PV_ViewModel : ObservableObject
{

  .....

    public string DocumentSource
    {
        get { return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_documentsource)? (_documentsource = @"about:blank") : _documentsource); }
        set { SetField<string>(ref _documentsource, value, "DocumentSource"); }
    }

  .....        

    public PV_ViewModel()
    {
        PropertyChanged += DocumentSourceChanged;
    }

  .....        

    protected void DocumentSourceChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            switch(e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "DocumentSource":
                    {
                        // show the document and whatsoever
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
  .....
```

}

Neither the getter nor the setter of the viewmodel DocumentSource property get accessed from anywhere, despite the UserControl in MainWindow had is DocumentSourceProperty filled in with the current document path string. (i can see it form a collection of currently opened document on the main app).

To clarify: the application solution contains MainWindow project (the main view, a simple window with a TreeView and the UserControl container), the UserControl project (the (hopefully) standalone application used to show a single document when providing the path to the doc to show through the DocumentSource property.

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure I understand your problem (or if you understand how Dependency Properties work), so you may have to post a bit more of your code behind (with the DI for example)

Typically your `DocViewerControl` looks like this

```
public abstract class DocViewerControl : UserControl
{
    public string Path
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Path", typeof(string), typeof(DocViewerControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

}
```

This will expose a Property in XAML of the control.

It's important here that you make it TwoWay binding, so any change from the UserControll will update the bounded field in your ViewModel.

Your ViewModel:

```
public class Doc1ViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    private string path;
    public string Path
    {
        get { return path;}
        set { 
            if(path!=value) {
                path = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Path");
            }
        }
}
}
```

Now, each time when you assign the property in your **UserControl**, the value in the ViewModel will be updated. As you can see, the Dependency Property consists from two properties. One `static` Dependency Property called `PathProperty` and one instance property called `Path`.

But having a closer look at it, it's not a real instance property at all. It just wraps calls around the Dependency Property by using `GetValue` and `SetValue` (which are derived from DependencyObject class, which every UI control inherits).

Hope this clears it up how Dependency Properties work, as it hard to tell what's wrong with your approach without seeing the code used.

In a nutshell, Dependency Properties (together with Attached Properties) extend the XAML code with TwoWay bindable properties (normal instance property can only be bound in one direction).

Comment: I'm a bit late, sorry. As you can see i've already done what you mentioned above. What i want to know, to make an example, is 'How does a TextBox knows it's Text property has been set to a Value in XAML and how does it catch that value in code-behind?' (well, assuming a TextBox control uses a MVVM pattern, of course!)